# SQL: count occurrences for each row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQL table called `Codes` with a primary column `code` of type String.
I also have another table called `Items` with a column `codestring` also of type String. This entry always contains a string with some of the codes of the above table separated by spaces.
Now I want to get all codes and their number of Items containing the respective code. Can I do that?

Codes:

```
 code|...
 ----|---
"A0A"|
"A0B"|
  ...|
```

Items:

```
 ...|codestring
----|---------
    |"A0A C2B F1K"
    |"A0C D2S H3K"
    |...
```

Output:

Codes:

```
 code|...|noOfItems
 ----|---|---------
"A0A"|...|5
"A0B"|...|10
  ...|...|...
```

Comment: sample data and expected output is more appreciated

Comment: Also, what SQL dialect are you using; SQL Server, Oracle, MySql, Postgress, etc...?

Comment: SQLite for Swift

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: i don't create the data, i have to work with it, as it is

Comment: You mention swift so why not do it in swift instead of sql?

Comment: Try cleaning it with Safe Softwares FME workbench. It’s got a great visual GUI.

Comment: When inserting rows into the items table, split up that list so each element gets its own row. Only sane way in a database that lacks array types.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the codes are distinct (or at least no code is a substring of another code), you can use the LIKE operator:
(untested)

```
SELECT codes.code, count(*)
FROM codes LEFT JOIN items ON items.codestring LIKE '%' + codes.code + '%'
GROUP BY codes.code;
```

Comment: returns always 1 in the second column

Comment: Then replace the count(*) with items.codestring and remove the GROUP BY and see what you're getting.

Comment: Or (better): trying moving the ON clause to a WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

You have a horrible data format and should fix it.  The mapping to codes should have a separate row for each code.

If the codes are all three characters, then L Scott Johnson's answer is close enough.  Otherwise, you should take the delimiter into consideration:

```
SELECT c.code, count(i.codestring)
FROM codes c LEFT JOIN
     items i
     ON ' ' || i.codestring || ' ' LIKE '% ' || c.code || ' %'
GROUP BY c.code;
```

Note other fixes to the code:

- The concatenation operator is the standard `||`.
- The `count()` will return `0` if there are no matches.